# Sf2: Same url, two controllers depending on device

Tags: symfony, mobile, routes

Let's say that we have homepage under

```
http://foo.bar/
```

and controller that handles it:

```
class HomepageController extends FooController{

    public function homepageAction()
    {
         (some stuff)
    }
}
```

Homepage was desktop only, then it went RWD. Next step was writing separate views for desktop and mobile and wiring them up like this (simplified).

```
class HomepageController extends FooController{

    public function homepageAction()
    {
         (some stuff)

         if(true === $this->detector->isMobile())
         {
             return new Response($this->renderView('homepage.mobile.html.twig' [
                     'some' => $vars',
                 ]
             ));
         }

         return new Response($this->renderView('homepage.mobile.html.twig' [
                 'some'    => $vars',
                 'only'    => $for,
                 'desktop' => $version,
             ]
         ));      
    }
}
```

Now is the next step - make mobile version of homepage run on different controller. This is because desktop version gets so many data that is not required in mobile, causing current flow to be not optimized.

So, to sum it up, conditions:

1. mobile detector is already in project declared as a service,
2. homepage address cannot differ from desktop version,
3. desktop and mobile versions should run on separate controllers.

So far, only solution that I've found is to:
 1. always hit desktop controller,
 2. first action to do is to check if request comes from mobile,
 3. if yes, then forward internally to mobile homepage controller.

Sounds good, but I believe it can be done better!

I have another two theories about how do to that, but I don't want to propose them right now so noone gets influenced.

Comment: If the only difference is the template each time then you could use `return $this->render($this->detector->isMobile() ? 'homepage.mobile.html.twig' : 'homepage.desktop.html.twig', array())`

Comment: @Qoop this is the same solution we're already using. There's even a snippet of code handling this in my question. The real difference is performance, as desktop version requires far more data than mobile one.

Comment: Oh yeah.. I see that part now. I would say to create routes with an array of controllers like `_controller: { desktop: **desktop.controller.action**, mobile: **mobile.controller.action** }` and then change that attribute for the correct one in a `kernel.request` listener.

Comment: Sounds interesting, gonna try it out :)